# Tensorflow on OSX: Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime (No module named pywrap_tensorflow_internal)

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip

I'm trying to install Tensorflow (r1.2) on my MacBook (OSX 10.12.5).
The installation works, but I'm getting errors, when I try to import TF in python.

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import tensorflow as tf
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
  ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  ImportError: No module named pywrap_tensorflow_internal


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I'm working in a `virtualenv` (using `virtualenvwrapper`) with up-tp-date packages

- python 2.7.10
- pip 9.0.1
- numpy 1.13.1
- wheel 0.29.0
- six 1.10.0

I tried to install the default pip package (no GPU support) using `pip install tensorflow`, first.
Afterwards I also tried to install tensorflow from source following the [installation tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources), without CUDA support (configure script said `No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow`). Building and installing reported no errors, but I got the same error when I tried to import tensorflow.

Related questions/answers pointed out problems with CUDA or missing Windows dll files, which do not seem to fit my problem.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.i did this

First

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

Download this [tensorflow wheel](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/blob/master/1.6.0/py36/CPU/sse2/tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl) file

Now install this using(in same Directory)

```
pip install tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is same to yours.

I deleted the tensorflow with "rm -r ~/tensorflow ",

and finally it working when I have reinstalled it

The detail is here:https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac#CommonInstallationProblems

Comment: You should consider adding the details into your own post (not via a link). Link destination might become unreachable for any reason and your answer would be unclear.